# How not to include input file if empty in php mysql query

Tags: php, mysql, isset

This is my approach but it doesnt work if the input file(image) is empty when updating it. I want if the input FILE is empty it will not update the $file in database. but if there's a FILE it will update. that's why I have 2 query in IF ELSE.

```
 <?php

    if (!isset($_FILES['image']['tmp_name'])) {
    mysql_query("UPDATE profile set name ='".$_POST['name']. "', age ='".$_POST['age']. "', bdate ='".$_POST['bdate']."', bplace ='".$_POST['bplace']."', educ ='".$_POST['educ']."', occu ='".$_POST['occu']."', inc ='".$_POST['inc']."', status ='".$_POST['status']."', addr ='".$_POST['addr']."', contact ='".$_POST['contact']."', probpres ='".$_POST['probpres']."', findings ='".$_POST['findings']."', evalreco ='".$_POST['evalreco']."', recom ='".$_POST['recom']."', lastdate =  DATE_FORMAT(NOW(),'%m-%d-%Y %h:%i %p')  WHERE app_id = '".$_POST['app_id1']."'");
    }
    else {
    $file=$_FILES['image']['tmp_name'];
    $image= addslashes(file_get_contents($_FILES['image']['tmp_name']));
    $image_name= addslashes($_FILES['image']['name']);
    move_uploaded_file($_FILES["image"]["tmp_name"],"photos/" . $_FILES["image"]["name"]);
    $image_save ="photos/" . $_FILES["image"]["name"];
        /*with file in query*/
    mysql_query("UPDATE profile set name ='".$_POST['name']. "', age ='".$_POST['age']. "', bdate ='".$_POST['bdate']."', bplace ='".$_POST['bplace']."', educ ='".$_POST['educ']."', occu ='".$_POST['occu']."', inc ='".$_POST['inc']."', status ='".$_POST['status']."', addr ='".$_POST['addr']."', contact ='".$_POST['contact']."', photo ='$image_save',  probpres ='".$_POST['probpres']."', findings ='".$_POST['findings']."', evalreco ='".$_POST['evalreco']."', recom ='".$_POST['recom']."', lastdate =  DATE_FORMAT(NOW(),'%m-%d-%Y %h:%i %p')  WHERE app_id = '".$_POST['app_id1']."'");
    }
    ?>
```

Comment: Can you clarify what you mean please? Do you mean that you wish to update the database ONLY IF the file exists?

Comment: its like you will not update the file path in the database. all of them has an $image file path. the problem is when they update their profile they must need to insert image profile again.

Answer (score 0):

You could try something like the following - not tested but looks OK. I assume that the form is set to `POST` and also that the enctype is set as `multipart/form-data`

```
<?php
    $sql="UPDATE `profile` set 
            `name`='".$_POST['name']. "',
            `age`='".$_POST['age']. "',
            `bdate`='".$_POST['bdate']."',
            `bplace`='".$_POST['bplace']."',
            `educ`='".$_POST['educ']."',
            `occu`='".$_POST['occu']."',
            `inc`='".$_POST['inc']."',
            `status`='".$_POST['status']."',
            `addr`='".$_POST['addr']."',
            `contact`='".$_POST['contact']."',
            `probpres`='".$_POST['probpres']."',
            `findings`='".$_POST['findings']."',
            `evalreco`='".$_POST['evalreco']."',
            `recom`='".$_POST['recom']."',
            `lastdate`=DATE_FORMAT( NOW(),'%m-%d-%Y %h:%i %p') ";

    /* Perhaps a bit of overkill with detection but better safe than sorry */
    if( isset( $_FILES ) && is_array( $_FILES ) && array_key_exists( 'image', $_FILES ) && array_key_exists('name',$_FILES['image']) && !empty( $_FILES['image']['name'] ) ){

        /* The user HAS uploaded a file so add the photo/file and the where clause */

        /* Perform image manipulation / saving etc */
        $tmpfile=$_FILES['image']['tmp_name'];
        $filename=$_FILES['image']['name'];

        $image=file_get_contents( $tmpfile );
        $image_name=addslashes( $filename );

        $image_save="photos/" . $filename;
        move_uploaded_file( $tmpfile, $image_save );

        /* add elements to query */
        $sql .= ", `photo` ='".$image_save."' WHERE `app_id`='".$_POST['app_id1']."';";

    } else {
        /* The user has NOT uploaded a file so just add the where clause */
        $sql .= "WHERE `app_id`='".$_POST['app_id1']."';";
    }

    mysql_query( $sql );

?>
```

Comment: still not working. I'm getting this error: warning: file_get_contents(): Filename cannot be empty

Comment: its working now using this : if (!isset($_FILES['image']['tmp_name']) or empty ($_FILES['image']['tmp_name'])) {